# Deploying JSP to Google App Engine using Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jsp, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I haven't been able to deploy my project on Google App Engine for the last week. I am deploying it as a Standard Java Project from Eclipse (not Maven, not Flex.)

I am getting an error : "Process exited with error Code 1" but cannot have any stack trace.
Deploying the Hello World example project works fine but adding any simple JSP (even without JSP or JSTL instructions) makes the bug occur.

I reinstalled Java JDK, I'm using JDK 1.8.0_141 and pointing to the JDK (not the JRE.)
Also reinstalled Eclipse, Google Cloud Tools, Cloud Tools SDK to no avail.

Very weird, any suggestion is welcome.

Thanks in advance

Comment: which version of the plugin are you running? Did you update the plugin last week?

Comment: Updated 1 or 2 weeks ago : 1.2.0.201706082053

Comment: Should I downgrade ? can only see update in Eclipse Marketplace and don't know how to do.

Comment: potentially related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45261960/how-fix-new-error-thats-stopping-app-engine-deployment-after-google-pushed-a#comment77526522_45261960

Comment: will check, thanks

Comment: Cannot revert to 158.
I am launching install.bat from python-bundled sdk directory but just tells "Google Cloud SDK Installer will now exit". I have uninstalled most recent version but still not installing, any hint pls ? Tx

Comment: Just to be clear, you're using _Deploy to App Engine Standard_ and seeing `Process exited with error Code 1` in the deployment console?

Answer (score -1):

You just need to configure your project with JDK not JRE .

Comment: The author specifically stated that this is not the issue.